# BluetoothAdapter notification when a bluetooth device is unboded

Tags: android, events, bluetooth

Function
 `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices()`
returns a list of available connected bluetooth devices

Can I get a notification if one of those devices suddenly becomes disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all getBondedDevices() returns not connected devices. These devices are paired or bonded and that's all. Connection establishes by socket.connect().
The second thing. You can register a broadcast receiver for all events such bond state changed or device is connected \ disconnected.

See more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)